# How do I split a string at character and subset the left or right side?

Tags: r

Say I have a file of characters that I would like to split at a character and then select the left side of the split to a new field.  Is there a way to do this one step?  For example:

```
x <- strsplit('dark_room',"_")
x[[1]][2]
[1] "room"
```

Is a two-step operation to access the "room" - how can I subset "room" in one operation?

Comment: A `gsub` option similar to `sub` below: `gsub("([a-z]+)_([a-z]+)","\\2","dark_room")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier option is to use `word` from `stringr` and specify the `sep` and other parameters

```
library(stringr)
word('dark_room', -1, sep="_")
#[1] "room"
```

---

Or with `str_extract` to match characters other than `_` (`[^_]+`) at the end (`$`) of the string

```
str_extract('dark_room', "[^_]+$")
#[1] "room"
```

Or with `stri_extract` from `stringi` where we can specify the `first` and `last`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_first('dark_room', regex = '[^_]+')
#[1] "dark"
stri_extract_last('dark_room', regex = '[^_]+')
#[1] "room"
```

---

The `strsplit` always returns a `list`.  So, as a general case (applicable when there are more than one element) would be to loop through the `list` with `sapply` and subset with either `tail`

```
sapply( strsplit('dark_room',"_"), tail, 1)
#[1] "room"
```

or `head` to get the first `n` elements

Or using `scan`

```
tail(scan(text = 'dark_room', what = "", sep="_"), 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using `sub` from base R which just removes everything up to the first underscore -

```
# for left side of '_'
sub(".*_", "", x)    
[1] "room"

# for right side of '_'
sub("(.*)_.*", "\\1", x)
[1] "dark"
```

Answer (score 2):

Define your own functions (using the solution in your question or any of the other solutions from the answers)

```
left = function(x, sep){
    substring(x, 1, regexpr(sep, x) - 1)
}
right = function(x, sep){
    substring(x, regexpr(sep, x) + 1, nchar(x))
}

s = c("dark_room")

left(s, "_")
#[1] "dark"

right(s, "_")
#[1] "room"
```